# Qt - how to detect what application is in focus

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Is it possible to know what application is in focus using Qt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use some Win32 API functions. Mainly GetActiveWindow(). Search MSDN for the function.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about other apps, but you can tell whether your own application has the focus or not by checking for a 0 result from [QApplication::activeWindow](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qapplication.html#activeWindow).